# How can I point to the correct location to the parent pom?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I had to re-install Eclipse, and my previously-working project refuses to compile due to Maven POM error.

The error is

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer my:my-parent:pom:3.0 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.
>   Original error: Could not transfer artifact my:my-parent:pom:3.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/
>    maven2): connect timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

I know the SVN location for the parent POM on the company Intranet, but not sure where it should be configured in Eclipse/Maven so parent POM is read from there instead of from Apache Maven repo

Comment: you have to check out the parent. in your settings.conf of mvn you can define your repos. so there are two things to consider depending on how your project is configured. you have to import your settings of maven to eclipse-> maven-> usersettings if you want to have the same behaviour in eclipse and in terminal. at the end your question is very wide.

Comment: You maven settings.xml is not placed correctly, you either need to put that in .m2 folder in your home directory or if its a custom location you can update eclipse to look it there ( preferences -> maven -> User Settings)

Answer (score 0):

You must configure current maven repositories in your .m2 directory in settings.xml file.
And if you want to force to check for artifacts in remote repositories you must do a mvn compile with -U option to force an update

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you are in company network may be a proxy issue. Check the settings.xml and check the required proxy is setup properly
2. Try force maven update

   mvn clean install -U

Answer (score 0):

As per NullPointerException's comment, the problem was that my previous Eclipse install had a custom .m2 location ( preferences -> maven -> User Settings ) and new install was pointing to incorrect .m2.

Changing that to correct location fixed the issue